# 500 (Internal Server Error) while adding data in local development for LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-local-development

I'm getting below error when I'm trying to add data using local development:
POST http://localhost:3333/webruntime/api/apex/execute 500 (Internal Server Error).

In Network tab in Preview I see also:
message:"error parsing or finding aura config: window.Aura not found"

PS: I'm using scratch org.

Js file:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class FlashcardManager extends LightningElement {
    flashcards = [];
    englishWord;
    polishWord;

    handleChange(event) {
        const { name, value } = event.target;

        if (name === "englishWord") {
            this.englishWord = value;

        } else if (name === "polishWord") {
            this.polishWord = value;
        }
    }

    addFlashcardHanlder() {
        const flashcard = {
          polishword: this.polishWord,
          englishWord: this.englishWord
        };
      
        addFlashcard({ payload: JSON.stringify(flashcard) })
          .then(result => {
            if (result) {
              console.log("Added flashcard");
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log("Error in adding flashcard: ", error);
          });
      }
      
}
```

Cls file:

```
public with sharing class FlashcardController {
  public FlashcardController() {
  }

  @AuraEnabled
  public static string addFlashcard(String payload) {
    try {
      Flashcard payloadObject = (Flashcard) JSON.deserialize(
        payload,
        Flashcard.class
      );
      SObject flashcard = (SObject) Type.forName('Flashcard__c').newInstance();
      flashcard.put('English_word__c', payloadObject.englishWord);
      flashcard.put('Polish_word__c', payloadObject.polishWord);

      insert flashcard;

      return String.valueOf(flashcard.Id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
  
  public class Flashcard {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String flashcardId;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String englishWord;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String polishWord;
  }  
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Should I repair local development somehow?
Should I add some configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Something changed about Lightning Out in Summer 23. Deactivating the release update "Security Enhancements for CSRF Tokens for Lightning Apps" resolved the issue for me. ([Original answer](https://github.com/forcedotcom/lwc-dev-server-feedback/issues/155#issuecomment-1589768104))

[image: Disable Security Enhancements for CSRF Tokens for Lightning Apps Update]

You might need to run `npm install` on your project to make sure that all the packages are properly installed.